django cannot access from same LAN after runserver ip:port
Please help for my problem I'm new in django programming, my rpoblem is when I use localhost can direct to dashboard but when I use Local IP got error message and still in login menu,bellow is error message from console:
The Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy header has been ignored, because the URL's origin was untrustworthy. It was defined either in the final response or a redirect. Please deliver the response using the HTTPS protocol. You can also use the 'localhost'
Refused to execute script from 'http://192.168.0.81:8000/static/vendor/libs/%40form-validation/umd/plugin-bootstrap5/index.min.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
for setting.py
ALLOWED_HOSTS = \['192.168.0.81', 'localhost', '127.0.0.1'\]

SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True

CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'staticfiles'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'


Do you perhaps have the DEBUG setting configured as False?

Try running your server with this command
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000

Do you have these lines added in urls.py?
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns = urlpatterns + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

Next, If you are running the server with DEBUG = False, change it to True
If it still doesn't work, try different browsers and provide more debug info

"The Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy header has been ignored, because the URL's origin was untrustworthy." This answer doesn’t solve the aforementioned problem.

You have a space character which is being added to your url. Note the %40 that is an http encoded whitespace.
If you were to navigate to: http://192.168.0.81:8000/static/vendor/libs/form-validation/umd/plugin-bootstrap5/index.min.js does the request work. (Note i removed the %40 from the url.
If this works then it would assume there is a whitespace character which has been added somewhere by mistake.
Now the reason you are getting the html mimetype error. Is you have a <script> tag which is trying to run a django http404 page.
